# Need help finding what this component is - top marking L5 (sideways X)

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I am currently working on a GPS and I am having trouble finding what exactly this component is. Can someone help me identify it?

First photo: component
Second photo: removed component with nearby components
Thirst photo: wider angle photo with removed component

The cable port nearby is NMEA2000, is used for communicating different marine equipments. It carries 12V and data. The GPS was struck by lightning and all equipments onboard got a discharge on this port.

Thanks

[image: photo of microscope display showing unknown component]

[image: photo of removed component with nearby components]

[image: wider photo of component area]

Comment: Where its pads/leads connect to? This information might help.

Comment: Moy - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. As already commented, more context about the surrounding components, any reverse-engineered partial schematic which you have made etc., would all help. Please [Edit] the question to add any additional info. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your reply. Is my first time commenting on this website. I added some more information to the post. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that its a voltage regulator - maybe even a 5V regulator. Try to ascertain where the voltage rails are on the board. Find the supply pins of other chips on the pcb -- that will tell you where some of the rails are.

Comment: the 5 pin device might be a TC7SL04FU. The pins seem to line up. This is a single inverter. probably used to buffer an input or output. The SOT23-3 looks like a transistor at a guess.